# Proving continuity of two variable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Here is the function I'm looking at:
f(x,y) =
\begin{array}{ll}
    \frac{x^4}{x^2 + y^2} & \text{for } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
    0 & \text{for } (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{array}

The question is to check if the function is continuous at zero using the epsilon delta definition. Here is my attempt:

Since $||x - a||$ < $\delta$, $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ < $\delta$, so
$|f(x,y) - 0|$ = $|f(x,y)|$ = $| \frac{x^4}{x^2 + y^2}|$ = $\frac{|x^4|}{||x,y||}$ \
$\leq$ $\frac{(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})^4}{||x,y||}$ = $||x,y||^3$, 
$lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}$ $||x,y||^3$ = $0$, thus the function is continuous.

I'm not sure if I'm using the definition correctly, and I'm not completely sure when the definition refers to norms or absolute values. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: $\frac{x^4}{x^2 + y^2}\leqslant \frac{x^4}{x^2 }=x^2$

Comment: How does this then show continuity at zero, would you not need to relate it to the norm and then take the limit of that?

Comment: What is limit of $x^2$ in $(0,0)$?